# Angular5: batch calls to get data for a filed in a json array

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, lodash

I have an array with json data in the below format

```
staff = [
{ "id"   : 1,
   "name" : "Robert"
},
{ "id"   : 2,
   "name" : "Peter"
}
]
```

I am trying to get the designation of these people. There is an API which accepts group of ids. I am trying to get designations in batches of 30. i.e send first 30 objects and get their designations and go on.. I tried keeping a for loop and pass 30 objects but unsuccessful.

Designation API gives data in the below format.

```
[
  {
    "staffId": "26",
    "designation": "PRA"
  },
  {
    "staffId": "25",
    "designation": "MRA"
  }
]
```

Result json

staff = [
    { "id"   : 1,
       "name" : "Robert",
    "staffDesignation": "PRA"
    },
    { "id"   : 2,
       "name" : "Peter",
    "staffDesignation": "MRA"
    }
    ]

So here for every 30 batches of designations that I get, I need to update the staff record with that value.

staff.component.ts

for (let i = 0; i <= this.staff.length; i++) {
  this.staffService.getStaffDesignator(//should pass 30 objects).subscribe((designator) => { //Here pass 30 objects
   //update designator logic
  },
    (err) => {

```
})
```

}

staff.service.ts

```
getStaffDesignator(staff)
{

    staff.forEach((staff, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        url = url + `?contactId=${staff.id}`;
      }
      else {
        url = url + `&contactId=${staff.id}`
      }
    }) //loop through the objects to get the staff id to pass to the APIcall

    return this.http.get(url, this.options)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
      })  //API call to get designations for staff

}
```

Comment: So will the `id` in `staff` array equal to the `staffId` in the designation array? Asking as you have given different values of those in your OP. And will this API return the data in an order in which the objects are present in the `staff` array?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes.. we get the key as staffId from the API call.. which is same as id in the staff record.

Comment: @indra257 In result josn how could you mange name in that? And you want to update key value as per result josn. Am I right ?

Comment: @SachinShah yes

Comment: @indra257 So basically you want to first call all API in batch of 30 and then you want to update key and value. Am I right ?

Comment: @SachinShah I need to call an API and pass 30 ids to it to get the designation. next call pass another 30 ids ... I need to update the staff object with the designations as soon as I get it. I shouldn't wait for all the calls to complete, because it takes lots of time. So I need to update the staff with the designation as soon as I get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you get res from API call then you can start to work in filter array process.

```
var filterArray = [];

this.http.post(url , param , header , function(err , response) => {
    // First way is to use map
    // You can use for loop 
    for(let i = 0 i < response.length ; i++){
         var obj = {
             id: response[i].staffId,
             name: response[i].name,
             staffDesignation: response[i].designation,
         }
         this.filterArray.push(obj);

         // Now you can call next API for another batch... 
    }
})
```

In this case , I suggest you can use this below structure.

**step1 :** Make a array of 30 batches.

**step2 :** Use for loop with `Observable`.

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < this.array.length ; i++){       //Each i has batch of 30.

     // Hear observable will work as a promise in for loop to make call in sync.
     return new Observable((observer) => {
          return http.post(url , param , option)...

         //Once you got data from API use my above code to filter your
         // Key and value from res. 

        observable.next();
        observable.complete(); // It will go for call next batch... 
     })
}
```

Comment: I don't think we are making calls in batches of 30

Comment: @indra257 I have update my answer. Please check it. :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't see i has a batch of 30. Am I missing something?

Comment: That you have to set batch from your side. We are just help you in idea.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `staff` data as:

```
staff = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Robert"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Peter"
  }
]
```

And your API returns the data in the same order in which it was requested,

You can get the staffIds as:

```
staffIds = staff.map(item => item.id);
```

Once you call your API and get the `response`, you can then merge the response with the `staff` array like this:

```
resultingArray = Object.values(
  [...staff, ...response]
  .reduce((r, { staffId, id = staffId, ...rest }) => ({
    ...r,
    [id]: { id, ...r[id], ...rest }
  }), {})
);
```

Comment: But I need to make calls in batches. like pass first 30 objects and get their designation and repeat the process. I have nearly 1000 staff, so I have to make call in batches for better performance.

Comment: I don't think here we are making calls in batches of 30

Comment: @indra257, I've clearly mentioned in the answer that ONCE YOU GET THE DATA, you can merge the response with the `staff` array. Since you haven't really shared how you're making the API call, I can't really add anything random to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Please find the updated question with what I have tried so far. I haven't figured out how to pass objects in batches of 30. Staff service will loop through it to get ids and pass to the API