# How to make a sequence of http requests in Angular 6 using RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I've been looking for a solution all over the web, but couldn't find anything that fits my user case. I'm using the MEAN stack (Angular 6) and I have a registration form. I'm looking for a way to execute multiple HTTP calls to the API and each one is dependent on the returned result from the previous one. I need something that looks like this:

```
firstPOSTCallToAPI('url', data).pipe(
    result1 => secondPOSTCallToAPI('url', result1)
    result2 => thirdPOSTCallToAPI('url', result2)
    result3 => fourthPOSTCallToAPI('url', result3)
    ....
).subscribe(
    success => { /* display success msg */ },
    errorData => { /* display error msg */ }
);
```

What combination of RxJS operators do I need to use to achieve this? One possible solution would be to nest multiple subscriptions, but I want to avoid that and do it better with RxJS. Also need to think about error handling.

Comment: Is your number of observables defined ? Or does the code has to be dynamic ?

Comment: you can use flatMap or switchMap

Comment: rguerin, I would like to be flexible and not depend on exact number of observables.  

@JEY I tried using switchMap but i get an error saying "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3". Can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For calls that depend on previous result you should use `concatMap`

```
firstPOSTCallToAPI('url', data).pipe(
    concatMap(result1 => secondPOSTCallToAPI('url', result1))
      concatMap( result2 => thirdPOSTCallToAPI('url', result2))
       concatMap(result3 => fourthPOSTCallToAPI('url', result3))
    ....
).subscribe(
    success => { /* display success msg */ },
    errorData => { /* display error msg */ }
);
```

if your async method does not depend on return value of the precedent async call you can use

```
   concat(method(),method2(),method3()).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you very much, you have ended my suffering!

Comment: You beautiful human!!  Got me out of a bind here.  Thanks!

Comment: I found this very helpful. https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Comment: @Drenai yep `switchMap` and `mergeMap` is also applicable here. Since http is one off emission

Comment: How would i get access to result1 or result2 in the success part at the end

Comment: you can pass down stream with `map` : 
    concatMap(result1 => secondPOSTCallToAPI('url', result1).pipe(map(result2=>[result1,result2])

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same problem, this is my solution use `pipe` and `concatMap` for array for get sequence data for time period between start and end time.

This is general solution when we have array request.

I share for whom concern.

```
 let currentReplayData = [];
 let timerange = [[t1, t2], [t3, t4]]; // array of start and end time
 from(timerange).pipe(
      concatMap(time => <Observable<any>>this.dataService.getData(time[0],time[1]))
      ).subscribe(val => {
        //console.log(val)
        this.currentReplayData = this.currentReplayData.concat(val);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

## `MergeMap`

is exact what you are looking for

```js
firstPOSTCallToAPI('url', data).pipe(
    mergeMap(result1 => secondPOSTCallToAPI('url', result1)),
    mergeMap(result2 => thirdPOSTCallToAPI('url', result2)),
    mergeMap(result3 => fourthPOSTCallToAPI('url', result3)),
    // ...
).subscribe(
    success => { 
      // here you will get response of LAST request (fourthPOSTCallToAPI)
    },
    errorData => { /* display error msg */ }
);


// I assume that
// secondPOSTCallToAPI, thirdPOSTCallToAPI and fourthPOSTCallToAPI
// returns obserwable eg. return this.http.get<Book>(apiUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public requestDataFromMultipleSources(): Observable<any[]> {
    let response1 = this.http.get(requestUrl1);
    let response2 = this.http.get(requestUrl2);
    let response3 = this.http.get(requestUrl3);
    return Observable.forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]);
  }
}

The above example shows making three http calls, but in a similar way you can request as many http calls as required

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page',
    templateUrl: './page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    public responseData1: any;
    public responseData2: any;
    public responseData3: any;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.requestDataFromMultipleSources().subscribe(responseList => {
            this.responseData1 = responseList[0];
            this.responseData2 = responseList[1];
            this.responseData3 = responseList[1];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how to here, assuming I have much of emails I want to deliver an email to sequentially:

```
sendEmails() {
  this.isLoading = true; 
            const calls = this.emails <<-- assume this contain an array of emails
            .map(email => this.userEmailService.deliver({email: email, userId: 1242}));
            from(calls) <<-- make use of the from.
                .pipe(
                    concatMap(res => res),
                    finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
                ).subscribe(() => { });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Try this , Angular provides feature to call multiple API at a time.

```
forkJoin()
```

You will get data in `array` as in same sequence which you call API.

Ex:

```
forkJoin(request1, request2)
    .subscribe(([response1, response2]) => {
```

You can find more [read](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

I have also given another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214402/angular5-batch-calls-to-get-data-for-a-filed-in-a-json-array/53214868#53214868). Please check this, it may also helps you.

Comment: `forkJoin` sends all at once AFAIK, using `concat` ensures the previous one completes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked into forkJoin but it doesn't look like a working solution since i need request2 to use response data returned from request1.

Comment: In that case , forkJoin will not use. I suggest to check second link. It will work in you case.