# Angular - Multiple conditional http requests

Tags: angular

I'm struggling a bit with coming up with a good solution for doing multiple http requests, based on the result of each of them. So far, I've been doing good with switchMap, as long as it's only 2 http requests. However, I've found out I need to perform 3, and I'm not sure how to do it with switchMap, or if there's a better solution for it.

Basically, I will await a response, and if it comes back empty, I want to perform a 2nd request, and if that comes back empty, I want to perform a 3rd request.

Let me try to give a simplified example of what I've gotten so far:

```
getData(): Observable<number> {
  const $subject = new Subject<number>();

  // loadData() takes in an id to specify what data to load
  service.loadData(1).pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
      if(response.length === 0) {
        return service.loadData(2);
      }
      else {
        return of(response);
      }
    }),
  ).subscribe(result => {
    $subject.next(result);
    $subject.complete();
  });
  return $subject.asObservable();
```

Now this works just fine, my issue is, that calling "loadData(2)", might also give back a response with length = 0, and in that case, I need to call loadData(3).

I tried having another switchMap within the switchMap, but that didn't seem to work properly. So my question is, how would I be able to check the length of the response of loadData(2), and if it's 0, return service.loadData(3) ?

Any help or tips are very welcome :)

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53560996/2050306

Comment: @robert While this answer does look useful, I can't see how it takes the response of each observable into consideration - In my scenario, most cases I will only need to do the first call, while this suggestion seems to always perform all 3 calls

Answer (score 2):

One straight forward and ugly way would be to subscribe to each call individually and check it's result.

```js
getData(): Observable<number> {
  const $subject = new Subject<number>();

  service.loadData(1).subscribe(
    loadOneResponse => {
      if(loadOneResponse.length === 0) {
        service.loadData(2).subscribe(
          loadTwoResponse => {
            if(loadOneResponse.length === 0) {
              service.loadData(3).subscribe(
                loadThreeResponse => {
                  $subject.next(loadThreeResponse);
                  $subject.complete();
                },
                loadThreeError => {
                }
              );
            } else {
              $subject.next(loadTwoResponse);
              $subject.complete();
            }
          },
          loadTwoError => {
          }
        );
      } else {
        $subject.next(loadOneResponse);
        $subject.complete();
      }
    },
    loadOneError => {
    }
  );

  return $subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something like this, but I feel like there should be a more elegant approach to this - I might end up doing this though, in case I don't find something better. Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, there might something more elegant, but sometimes the simple way too doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: Thank you, I was facing something similar and got a solution working from your idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960012/738690

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `from` with `pipe`

and `takeWhile -> concatMap -> filter -> tap` operators.

`getData` in service will receive an array of id numbers to try getting data for.

`from` will emit each id from the `ids` array.

`concatMap` does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes.

`filter` will ignore empty results.

`takeWhile` will cancel the whole stream once `take` becomes `false`

```
  getData(ids: number[]): Observable<number[]> {
    let take = true;
    return from(ids).pipe(
      takeWhile(() => take),
      concatMap(id => this.getDataFromApi(id)),
      filter(result => result.length > 0),
      tap(() => take = false)
    );
  }
```

Sample usage in the component:

```
  handleGetData() {
    console.log("component: getData");
    const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.dataService.getData(ids).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("got data: ", data);
    });
  }
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwgjui?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)