# Run multiple observables sequentially and in order

Tags: rxjs

I want to chain multiple observables in a single **stream** and preserve the previous value further down the pipe chain.

Each observable must run **sequentially** (one after the other, example: if the first observable completes it must go to the next one) and the order is important. I don't want to subscribes to them in parallel (just like **forkJoin**)

The output must give me the user info, cellphones, addresses and the email of the user.

I can do it with **switchmap**, this approach does work; but is there a better approach?

Just a dummy example:

```
    this.userService.getUser(id)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(userResponse => {
            return this.cellphoneService.getCellphones(userResponse.id)
                .pipe(
                    map(cellphonesResponse => [userResponse, cellphonesResponse])
                )
        }),
        switchMap(([userResponse, cellphonesResponse]) => {
            return this.emailService.getEmails(userResponse.id)
                .pipe(
                    map(emailResponse => [userResponse, cellphonesResponse, emailResponse])
                )
        }),
        switchMap(([userResponse, cellphonesResponse, emailResponse]) => {
            return this.addressService.getAddresses(userResponse.id)
                .pipe(
                    map(addressResponse => [userResponse, cellphonesResponse, emailResponse, addressResponse])
                )
        }),
    ).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560652/how-to-make-a-sequence-of-http-requests-in-angular-6-using-rxjs/53560996#53560996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mapping your response to an array after each call, you can instead nest your switchMaps, then all responses will be in scope, so you can just use a single map:

```js
this.userService.getUser(id).pipe(
   switchMap(user => this.cellphoneService.getCellphones(user.id).pipe(
      switchMap(cellphones => this.emailService.getEmails(user.id).pipe(
         switchMap(email => this.addressService.getAddresses(user.id).pipe(
            map(address => [user, cellphones, email, address])
         ))
      ))
   ))
).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```

This is described in a little more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386585/how-to-pass-results-between-chained-observables/63462962#63462962)

Comment: @BizzyBop Is ``concat`` a good approach too? I was reading that ``concat`` runs multiples observables in sequence. And Is it bad practice to use many nested ``switchMap``?

Comment: It depends on the situation. Concat provides a different behavior. It will emit the result for each of its source observable. The solution above emits only one time after all “sources” emit. Also, with concat, you  will not have access to emissions from other observables. I do not believe having bested switchMaps is inherently bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **observable of observables**. The `concatAll` operator will subscribe to each one of them in order but only one at a time. Meaning that `concatAll` first subscribes to `name$` and emits its value. Then `name$` completes and `concatAll` moves to `email$`, etc.

In the end `concatAll` will emit three values but `reduce` will accumulate these values into one array. Thus the `data$` stream emits only once.

```js
const name$ = timer(250).pipe(
  map(() => 'john doe'),
  tap(str => console.log(`received: ${str}`))
);

const email$ = timer(150).pipe(
  map(() => 'johndoe@example.com'),
  tap(str => console.log(`received: ${str}`))
);

const phone$ = timer(50).pipe(
  map(() => '777 555 666'),
  tap(str => console.log(`received: ${str}`))
);

const data$ = from([name$, email$, phone$]).pipe(
  concatAll(),
  reduce((acc, data) => acc.concat(data), [])
);

data$.subscribe(d => console.log('emitted:', d));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {from, timer} = rxjs;
const {map, tap, concatAll, reduce} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```